# Deploy artifact using deploy plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using maven deploy plugin to deploy an artifact to repository.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>aqua-deploy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>./deploy/sample.zip</file>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <artifactId>standalonehostrelease</artifactId>
                        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                        <packaging>zip</packaging>
                        <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}</repositoryId>
                        <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Currently I have defined distributionManagement in the pom.xml to get the repositoryId and the url.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>name</name>
        <urlurl</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>name</name>
        <urlurl</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have a requirement where I have to get the repositoryId  and url from the setting.xml.Is it possible to point to my settings.xml and get the repositoryId  and url and avoid distribution management in pom.

Comment: first it does not make sense to use deploy plugin in that way..cause dependencyManagement is intended for this purpose so why would you like to do something like this? What is the purpose for that?